# If I add a try-catch block with just Debugger.Break() in catch

Tags: c#, debugging, exception, release, try-catch

...will it effectively become an empty **try-catch** in the release build?

Or will it never make to the build?

```
try
{
   // do stuff...
   // do stuff...
}
catch
{
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

I know that **Debugger** calls won't be included - obviously, but does that apply to the **catch** I wrapped it in, too?

And is it a bad thing? It's just for debugging purposes - I want to see the exception right where it occurred, not where it leaves me after it bubbles up the stack. It's just more convenient.

Comment: you should `throw` *anyway* in the `catch`, even after a `Break()`

Comment: _"I know that Debugger calls won't be included - obviously"_, this is incorrect. It is true that `Debug.xxx` calls are not included when the `DEBUG` constant is set, but `Debugger.xxx` calls _are included always_. This makes sense, cause how would you otherwise be able to forcibly cause break in a release build? If you want this only in a debug build, wrap it in a method and add `Conditional("DEBUG")` to the attributes. Also, `Debugger.Launch()` may be more suitable in your scenario.

Comment: So, basically, the answer is **no, it won't result in an empty catch block** (and it won't do what you expect in a release build, it will show the WER crash dialog...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will result in an empty catch-block. To avoid this you can use conditial compilation sequences:

```
private void DoSomething()
{
#if DEBUG
    try
    {
#endif
        //do something
#if DEBUG
    }
    catch
    {
        Debugger.Break();
        throw;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: That changes the meaning though; the original *does not throw*.

Comment: It won't result in an empty catch block, `Debugger.Break()` is an instruction as anything else.

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer directly to your question, but did you know that Visual Studio has built in capabilities to break directly when an exception occurs?

You can find the functionality under Debug->Exceptions (or Ctrl+Alt+E)

See more at http://stevesmithblog.com/blog/visual-studio-break-when-exception-thrown/.

Comment: This feature is awsome ;) Easier to find culprits.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! My coworker didn't know that, either. Very convenient - although, when I set it and launched the app we inherited once again, I got knocked down by the amount of exceptions it's silently swallowing (such as (potentially) hundreds of Win32Exceptions when attempting to access all processes just to establish whether it is the only program instance running!?) ;)

Comment: If the program handles and recovers from exceptions, it can take some time to trim the settings to not break on those exceptions that are recovered from, but I think it's often worth it.

Comment: Yeah, I believe that. But still; in this case, raising so many exceptions is probably bad design to start with (to enforce no more than one instance at the time, one could just use a Mutex object afaik). So having to stop at every single exception actually helps bringing such stuff to light

Answer (score 1):

If you do this, it will break in debug mode and just ignore the caught exceptions in release mode. It's exactly equivalent to just putting a breakpoint on the catch which disappears in release mode. Just like having an empty catch block in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Or you might prefer this version:

```
private void DoSomething() 
{ 
  try     
  { 
    //do something 
  }     
  catch     
  {
#if DEBUG
    Debugger.Break();
#else
    throw;  // throws the exception using original call stack.
#endif
  }
}
```